# Logical Error in finding subsets

Tags: java, generics, subset

I'm trying to generalize the code to [find all subsets of a given string](https://github.com/nikhilbhardwaj/Recursion-Class/blob/master/05.Subsets/Subsets.java)(elements that are repeated will be treated as distinct) into one that would work for any list.

```
public class Subsets{
private static <T> void RecursiveSubsets(List<List<T>> list, ArrayList<T> soFar, List<T> rest)
{
if(rest.isEmpty())
{
  list.add(soFar);
}
else
{
  List<T> remaining;
  if(rest.size() == 1)
  {
    remaining = new ArrayList<T>();
  }
  else
  {
    remaining = rest.subList(1, rest.size() - 1);
  }
  //include the element
  ArrayList<T> includeFirst = new ArrayList<T>(soFar);
  includeFirst.add(rest.get(0));
  RecursiveSubsets(list, includeFirst, remaining);
  //exclude the element
  RecursiveSubsets(list, soFar, remaining);
 }
}

public static <T> List<List<T>> getAllSubsets(List<T> set)
{
List<List<T>> subsets = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
RecursiveSubsets(subsets,new ArrayList<T>(),set);
return subsets;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(){
  {
    add(0);add(1);add(2);add(3);
  }
};

List<List<Integer>> allSubsets = getAllSubsets(ints);
System.out.println("Total Subsets returned : " + allSubsets.size());
for(int i=0; i<allSubsets.size(); ++i)
  {
  for(int j=0; j<allSubsets.get(i).size(); ++j)
  {
    System.out.print(allSubsets.get(i).get(j) + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
  }
 }
}
```

After a few attempts I was able to get this to compile but this is what I get as output.
Even if I have more integers, it still returns this. I'm not able to figure out what I have missed and need help finding it.

```
$ java Subsets
Total Subsets returned : 4
0 1
0
1
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I read the question wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is actually almost correct, and you just have the sublist logic a bit wrong.

The javadoc for [List.sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) says

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

The word "exclusive" here is critical.

If you just change

```
remaining = rest.subList(1, rest.size() - 1);
```

to

```
remaining = rest.subList(1, rest.size());
```

your code works.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out. Its really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of this (in pseudocode) is typically:

```
List<List<T>> subsets( List<T> list ){

    if( list is empty ) return a list containing the empty list;

    // else:

    subsetsWithout = subsets( list w/o 0th element );

    result.addAll(subsetsWithout);

    for( subset in subsetsWithout )
        result.add( subset + list[0] )

    return result;
}
```

It looks like what you're doing is different, and the fact that you're trying to return things through the function parameters is making it more confusing.